# How to print a UIWebView via UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uiactivityviewcontroller, airprint

I have a view controller containing a `UIWebView` and a toolbar with an action/share button. This initializes and presents a `UIActivityViewController` object. Depending on whether I supply the `activityItems` parameter with either the web view's `URL` or the URL's corresponding `absoluteString`, different actions are offered, but the *Print* option is never shown (nor offered in the "more" section).

I do know how to print the web view contents explicitly using `UIPrintInfo` and `UIPrintInteractionController`, but that would be a separate toolbar button whereas I want to simply include the system's Print option into the activity button row. I assume printing a web view does not need any explicit coding.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Custom Activity For UIActivityCotnroller like this,

```
 import UIKit

protocol CustomActivityDelegate : NSObjectProtocol
{
    func performActionCompletion(actvity: CustomActivity)
}


class CustomActivity: UIActivity {

    var delegate: CustomActivityDelegate?


    override class var activityCategory: UIActivityCategory {
        return .action
    }

    override var activityType: UIActivityType? {
        guard let bundleId = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier else {return nil}
        return UIActivityType(rawValue: bundleId + "\(self.classForCoder)")
    }

    override var activityTitle: String? {
        return "You title"
    }

    override var activityImage: UIImage? {
        return <Your activity image >
    }

    override func canPerform(withActivityItems activityItems: [Any]) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func prepare(withActivityItems activityItems: [Any]) {
        //
    }

    override func perform() {
        self.delegate?.performActionCompletion(actvity: self)
        activityDidFinish(true)
    }
}
```

You can initialize this activity some thing like this

```
let customActivity = CustomActivity()
customActivity.delegate = self
```

And you can add this custom activity while preparing UIActivityController

```
let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [customActivity], applicationActivities: nil)
```

and you will also need to implement the call back method

```
func performActionCompletion(actvity: CustomActivity)
{
   //Perform you task
}
```

Note : This is just pseudo code, might contain error or syntax problems

Comment: Thank you for your clue. This is surprisingly complicated, I'd thought that printing a URL / `UIWebView`'s content would be more straightforward in iOS. Nevertheless, I think I'll implement it this way.

Comment: @stefan if your problem is solved please accept my answer

Comment: I'll happily do that if there doesn't come another idea for doing this in a shorter way – I hoped for a solution without explicit coding. Thanks again for your help!